# HOG Feature Extraction with NEON

Tags: image-processing, arm, computer-vision, neon

There are a different HoG implementations (OpenCV obviously) and I found some that have been optimized for SSE such as https://github.com/ivanaslamov/HoG_SSE. I'm looking for an HoG implementation leveraging ARM Neon. Any code available somewhere?

Comment: Why do you think open cv implementation is not optimized?

Comment: Because I read the code and there is no Neon used in the opencv_objdetect library. Some Neon is used in the core but not in objdetect.